# jQuery repeated event till user clicks on it

Tags: jquery

I have an animation on a partially hidden div container that will execute when the result returned from an ajax query is true. (The animation actually just brings the box into larger view, and then sliding it back in again)

```
$('#box').animate({'right':'-184px'}, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
$('#box').animate({'right':'-194px'}, 150, 'easeOutExpo');
```

How can I make this animation repeat every 4 seconds until the user clicks on `$('#box')`?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Based on jAndy's and rahul's code..this is how I'm thinking of implementing it (fictitious setting).

This is the code that starts the animation:

```
// declares the variable first or $('#stop').click() will return undefined variable
var intervalId = '';
$('#submit').submit(function () {
  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    $('#box').animate({'right':'-184px'}, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('#box').animate({'right':'-194px'}, 150, 'easeOutExpo');
  }, 4000);
});
```

This is the code that will supposedly will stop the animation:

```
$('#stop').click(function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function anibox(){
   $('#box').delay(4000).animate({'right':'-184px'}, {duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
   $('#box').animate({'right':'-194px'}, {duration: 150, easing: 'easeOutExpo', complete: anibox});
}
```

To start that animation just call

```
anibox()
```

anywhere in your code, to stop it use:

```
$('box').stop();
```

in your click event handler.
That is the 'jQueryish' way, without `setInterval()`.

Comment: Thanks jAndy! I tried your code and the .stop() doesn't stop the animation. It just keeps going on and on. Any idea where it's going wrong?

Comment: might be a typo.. $('#box').stop(); should do it

Comment: i fixed that in the original code but it didn't stop. I updated my implementation of yours and rahul's code in my question. Is there any reason why it might not be working? How I applied your code was instead of `var intervalId....` i entered anibox(). Also, I replaced `clearInterval...` with $('#box').stop();

Comment: Thank you jAndy! `$('#box').stop(true, true);` fixed it :) Many thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** and then assign it to a variable. When the user clicks on the $("#box") button call **[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)** passing the variable as the parameter.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){/*your code*/}, 4000);

$("#box").click(function(){
    clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Comment: You get the cookie for being first :) You almost lost if for the var name intervalid (what's an inter valid?) but I FTFY :)

Comment: since his only tag is jQuery and not 'javascript', I DESERVE IT :p /jk

Comment: @rahul I'm getting a intervalId is not defined error..is it anything to do with the "var intervalId.." code going into another submit() event? Is there also an elegant way of making the animation start first (without waiting 4 seconds once it's first triggered?). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I declared the variable with var intervalId = ''; and it fixed the not defined error. But the clearInterval(intervalId) isn't stopping the animation..any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if you use .delay() you could just append it after the last .animate() call

Answer (score 1):

use clearinterval or setinterval function of javascript for hiding dynamically created elements

check following link for more detail http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 1):

Starting the timer:

```
var timer = window.setInterval(yourAnimationFunction, 4000);
```

Killing the timer:

```
$('#box').click(function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```